# Shopify invalid token and password Error

Tags: php, api, shopify, postman

I am getting this error :

```
{
    "errors": "[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)"
}
```

Can anyone help me About the URL or why this error is coming. I am right now using Postman.

Url I am hitting :

```
https://{{token}}:{{pass}}@myStore.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json
```

Also can anyone tell me what's the pass here and token. Maybe that can be the error. 
I searched in shopify account there is no password in my app.
Is it my account password ? And also should this password be encoded or not ?

Maybe this answer is already given before but I didn't find it. Can you lead me to it also?

Comment: If you're using that in Postman - The `{{...}}` syntax is referencing a value in an environment file.

Comment: Your app is a private app or public app??

Comment: i am also getting same error, as i am using public app and the api url will be like below:  https://{api_key}:{shared_secret}@{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/products.json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are stuck in public apps for shopify.
Password is for Private Apps.
Rather going on the developer account, go to the main admin account OR
follow this URL:

[https://store_name.myshopify.com/admin/apps/private](http://#)

Here, you create a new private app and you will be able to find the password there.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

`Invalid API key or access token.` error response occurs in many conditions:

- When their access token or password is invalid. (Check whether the access token and password are correct pair of combinations in private app section.)
- Invalid access url. (Check the format of url. https://apikey:password@hostname/admin/resource.json)
- Invalid api permission. (Check for the permission applied on private app api from **Admin API permissions** section)

Answer (score 0):

**Shopify Theme Kit Command** : theme get --list -p=[password] -s="my-store.myshopify.com"

**Shopify Theme Kit Tip:**
Don't include the URL protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) in the store parameter.

**Solution**: Just remove Http/Https from the [-s=" "] store URL from the command.